# Restart or Loop a Rewound Animation in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a script that plays a movie clip backwards when it reaches the end, so the same animation plays back in reverse. All good so far.

When it goes back to the beginning it just stops. I want it to loop forever. Possible?

(Please note that I barely know AS. The below code is something I cobbled together from another source.)

```
var direct:String = "forward";

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame (event:Event):void {

if (Row_1.currentFrame > 99) {
direct = "backward";
}
var backAmount:Number = Row_1.currentFrame - 1;
if (direct == "backward") {
Row_1.gotoAndStop(backAmount);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make **direct** a Boolean, not a String, as there are only two possibilities.  A Boolean is much more efficient than a string for simple on/off functionality.

If the current frame equals the total length of the MovieClip, make direct false.

If the current frame equals the first frame of the MovieClip, make direct true.

If direct is true, the MovieClip plays forwards.

If direct is false, the MovieClip plays backwards.

```
var direct:Boolean = true;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame (event:Event):void {
    if (Row_1.currentFrame == Row_1.totalFrames) {
        direct = false;
    } else if (Row_1.currentFrame == 1) {
        direct = true;
    }

    if (direct) {
        Row_1.nextFrame()
    } else {
        Row_1.prevFrame()
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm. Thanks so much.